# Ubercart - Product discount based on total number of all products in cart

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart in Drupal for a simple web store.  I'm having trouble calculating a product discount based on the total number of all products in the cart. For example, I'm easily able to define discounts for if a user buys more than one of the same product, using the uc_custom_price module. But I want to give the discount if they buy more than one of any product. If they buy item 1 for 10 dollars and then add item 2 for 10 dollars, then I want both items to now cost 8 dollars.

Hopefully this makes sense. I searched the forums and googled for a couple of hours, but I just can't get this to work correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you explain the logic again please? What if item 1 costs $10 and  item 2 costs $15. What discount do you want to apply on each item?

Comment: Just two dollars off each.  So item 1 would be $8 and item 2 would be $13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Rules + Ubercart module. Or write custom code on order creation

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I haven't found anything better than this, so I'll use your answer.